# MySQL database container crashing when sending traffic?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

I have two docker containers -- one for my Wordpress site and another for the SQL database connected to it. When I run my website through an Availability Test like Uptrends, I receive 500 errors throughout.

It appears my container for the SQL database is crashing when it receives traffic that isn't a single visitor. I can even crash it just by refreshing over and over again. When viewing the live memory, I can see the memory and CPU usage start to increase, but it never passes 30-40% by the time it crashes and restarts.

My memory limit is currently at 990.7 MB. If I try to increase the memory limit with `sudo docker update --memory 2000M [container]`, I get an error that says "Your kernel does not support swap limit capabilities or the cgroup is not mounted. Memory limited without swap."

Any help here is extremely appreciated.

Comment: Can you check the MySql error logs?

Comment: You mean MySQL with `SQL`, right?

Comment: Please post last 400 lines from your error log prior to the crash and the lines from the error log recorded at the restart, please.